# P wrap A or A wrap P

Tags: html

what is the best way to make a link in html
i mostly use html4 but im trying to implement html5

so my question is basically what should be the wrapping tag, the p or a?

this:

```
        <p class="center">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="addToCart.png">
            </a>
        </p>
```

or this:

```
        <a href="#">
            <p class="center">
                <img src="addToCart.png">
            </p>
        </a>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under HTML 4.1 an `a` element, `display: inline` by default, cannot contain a block-level element, such as a `p`; therefore `p` should wrap `a`.

If, though, you're using HTML 5, and have `<!doctype html>`, then either way is acceptable (and valid), so use whichever you find best meets your requirements.

Comment: This is one of those places where HTML5 just paved the cowpaths. It's just a standardization of what's already supported.

Comment: True enough; but I deliberately stopped at the question of simple validity; browsers are (almost terminally) forgiving, so while invalid HTML is understood/supported it's still not *valid*. Even if it's able to function.

Comment: Does this affect the tabindex of the <a>?

Comment: It shouldn't, since the `p` isn't an interactive element (unless JavaScript has added functionality, or the `contentEditable` attribute is used to allow it), and shouldn't receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors can only contain inline elements (span, strong, em etc). Paragraph tags are block - and therefor not valid. Set the display:inline and it will certainly work, but its no longer valid.

Your first example is correct.

As noted = this is true in html4 only.

Comment: Please not that as per David's answer, this is only true for HTML 4. In HTML 5, the content restriction for `<a>` is [transparent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/terminology.html#transparent).

Comment: @david thomas - True enough

Answer (score 0):

Spec for [`<a>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-a-element.html#the-a-element)

Spec for [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-p-element.html#the-p-element)

In summary, both of the above can be used and are valid.  `<a>` has a transparent content model (with the exception of excluding other interactive content) so it can wrap practically anything.  `<p>` has "phrasing content" as its model, and `<a>` is in the phrasing content category.  `<img>` is also in "phrasing content."

Thus, both of your examples are totally valid.  It entirely depends on what you want to do specifically.